# How can I define the extent setting of environments programmatically in VBA?

Tags: arcobjects, vba

I use the following line of code to define the extent setting of the environments GP.Extent = "144566.589424822 351191.130242809 145772.160224822 353810.742942809". However, I need to define it programmatically via the boundaries of a layer like the procedure is carried out in any relevant window (e.g. in Clip window)
:'Environments'-'General Settings'-'Extent'-'Same as layer...'.
Thanks
Demetris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to find the rectangular extent of a feature. This will format it to a string you can use as an input to a geoprocessing tool or use it to set GP.Extent.

```
Dim pEnvelope As IEnvelope = pFeature.Shape.Envelope
Dim rectangle As String = ""
rectangle &= pEnvelope.XMin & " " & pEnvelope.YMin & " " & pEnvelope.XMax & " " & pEnvelope.YMax
```

Answer (score 0):

The interface IGeoDataset can be used to return the extent of a layer.